# How to pass layout property to page component in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am completely new to VueJS and NuxtJS.  I can't seem to pass a property in the layout to a page component.

This is my `layouts/default.vue`

```html
<template>
    <Nuxt myprop="hello world" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    myprop: 'hello galaxy',
  }),
}
</script>
```

This is my `pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>My Prop is: {{myprop}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    myprop: {
      type: String
      },
  },
}
</script>
```

When I load up my app, I expect to see `My Prop is: hello world`.  But instead, I see `My Prop is:`, and it seems `myprop` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?  How does a layout component pass a property to child component in VueJS or NuxtJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass props in that way, but you could use `provide/inject` pattern to pass the data from layout to the page :

**`layout/default.vue`**

```html
<template>
    <Nuxt  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  provide: function () {
    return { myprop: this.myprop };
  },
  data: () => ({
    myprop: 'hello galaxy',
  }),
}
</script>
```

**`pages/index.vue`**

```html
<template>
  <div>My Prop is: {{myprop}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ["myprop"],
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works for my context; I will keep it as an option. Alternatively I may just use VueX anyways since everything else is stored there globally.